# Re-using Angular components via NPM, with the ability to write custom html

Tags: angular, npm

I am not sure how to word this question correctly, but please bear with me.

We have built an Angular7 application, which works just fine. Now we've been tasked with creating an application with a lot of similarities in functionality, but with an entirely different layout.

I'd like to create NPM packages from the components that we have built, and then integrate those components in the new project. However, we'll need an option to override the HTML and SCSS files in the components.

Please respond if you have some best practices, documentation, tutorials or examples.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Angular elements was built for this use case

Answer (score 0):

i think you'd like create a custom library with yours component to import in more projects. Take a look to officially documentation: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries. You can find a lot of guides about this on the web.